# Random number for javascript/jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I have the following form fields:

```
1. [] [] [] x
2. [] [] [] x
3. [] [] [] x
4. [] [] [] x
```

[rand]

I allow the user to insert random numbers into the forms by clicking "rand":

```
1. [01] [09] [12] x
2. [03] [12] [13] x
3. [12] [15] [16] x
4. [01] [02] [03] x
```

[rand]

If the user so desires, they can delete a row and add a new one

```
1. [01] [09] [12] x
3. [12] [15] [16] x
4. [01] [02] [03] x
5. [] [] []  x
```

[rand]

Each row is named by its fields:

```
1. [01] [09] [12] = name=row_name[1][0], row_name[1][0], row_name[1][0]
3. [12] [15] [16] = name=row_name[3][0], row_name[3][0], row_name[3][0]
4. [01] [02] [03] = name=row_name[4][0], row_name[4][0], row_name[4][0]
5. [] [] []       = name=row_name[5][0], row_name[5][0], row_name[5][0]
```

[rand]

The problem I face is when a user deletes a number of rows, the sequences are now out of order, so instead of: 1,2,3,4 I have: 1,3,4,5

This means my random function will not work on row 5 since it is looking for 1,2,3,4 (in a for loop).

**So my dilemma is how best to code this...**

On the one hand, I am thinking of re-naming the fields each time a user deletes a row to keep them in sequence: 1,2,3,4

On the other hand I am thinking that I could just ignore the missing fields and improve how I insert the numbers.

**The rand function works as follows:**

```
var numbers_per_row = 3;
var total_numbers = 4;
var rows = getRandomNumbers(numbers_per_row,total_numbers);

This returns an array: [
   0 => [01,09,12],
   1 => [03,12,13],
   2 => [12,15,16],
   3 => [01,02,03]
]
```

Now that I have the array, I next need to insert the random numbers into the form fields:

```
var total_rows = rows.length();

for (var 1 = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {

    var line = row[i];
    for (var x =0; x < numbers_per_row; x++) {
        var field_name = 'row_name['+(i+1)+']['+x+'];
        $("#formName input[ name='" + field_main + "' ]").val(line[x]);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this function does not take into account the missing values that were deleted.

**I have been pondering the most logical way to go about this. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an array with the row numbers and delete the number if the row is being deleted. When a new row is inserted, add the row number to the array.

In this way, it is possible to iterate over the array with the row numbers and keep a working system.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this questions was pretty simple, thanks to Nina for the suggestions, this is what I did:

1. I created a row_map (an array with the keys of the form values)
2. On the create and delete function I added and removed the keys as required leaving the values as they are: [1,2,5,6,8,21,22,100].
3. When it came to the random number generator, I simply inserter the values at the given map location: which is imply: map[i] = current location...

Simple :)